# A combinatorics and algebra problem

Tags: combinatorics

I'm given two numbers $n$ and $m$. I have to make $n$ with $m$ numbers (only taking their sum). For example, if $n=6$, $m=3$, $6$ is formed with $3$ numbers in the following 
way:

- $1+1+4=6$
- $2+2+2=6$
- $1+2+3=6$

For every element of the sets above, if I use $C(r,2)$, $0<r<n$ and take their summation I get like this.

- $C(1,2)+C(1,2)+C(4,2)=0+0+6=6$
- $C(2,2)+C(2,2)+C(2,2)=3$
- $C(1,2)+C(2,2)+C(3,2)=4$

Here,we have considered $C(1,2)=0$.

One of my friend said to me that 
if we make $n$ with $m-1$ 1's plus $n-(m-1)$ then the sum of $C(r,2)$ will be maximum. In other words, the sum of $C(r,2)$ with $m-1$ 1's plus $n-(m-1)$ is always 
greater than the rest sums of $C(r,2)$.
In the above exapmle, $6$ is greater than $3$ and $4$.

My question is that why such a occurence happens? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Rewrite using LaTex please.

Comment: $C(r,2)$ stands for bnomial coefficients, i.e. $C(r,2)=\frac{r(r-1)}2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to consider two summands $a,b$ and verify that $C(a,2)+C(b,2)<C(1,2)+C(a+b-1,2)$ whenever $a,b>1$. Indeed, 
$$ C(a,2)+C(b,2) = \frac12(a^2-a+b^2-b)$$
$$ C(1,2)+C(a+b-1,2) = \frac12(a+b-1)(a+b-2)$$
and the difference is after simplification
$$C(1,2)+C(a+b-1,2) -(C(a,2)+C(b,2)) = \frac12(ab-a-b+1)=\frac12(a-1)(b-1)>0$$

Comment: Essentially, this is the inequality between quadratic and arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 0):

$C(n,2)$ equals the number of pairs in $n$ beans.  So $C(p,2)+C(q,2)+C(r,2)$ equals the number of pairs of beans where both beans are in the same set.
Suppose $p\leq q$, and we move one bean, $B$, from the $p$-set to the $q$-set.  We lose $p-1$ pairs, which are $B$ with each of the others from the $p$-set, but gain $q$ new pairs which are $B$ with each of the others in the new $q+1$ set.
So we have gained $q-(p-1)=q-p+1$ pairs.  Sending a bean from a small set to an equal or larger set increases the number of pairs.  So accumulate all - except 1 in each small set - in one big set will maximize the total number of pairs.